# Generate vector with sequence increasing according to an equation applied to the last generated number

Tags: r

I want to produce a vector starting at 1 and stopping at 900, where each increase is based on taking the last generated number and adding 1 and then multiplying it with 1.55; and then round it to the nearest number.

That is the sequence should be:

```
First number:  1 (i.e., start at 1)

Second number: 3 (i.e., (1+1)*1.55)

Third number:  6 (i.e., (3+1)*1.55)
```

I have tried:

```
 x0=1
 seq(x0, 600, (+1*1.55))
```

Comment: so third number is 6.2, you made it 6, when it get like after .5, you need `floor` or `ceil` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not so smart approach using `while` loop

```
stop = 900
new_num = 1
num = 1

while(new_num < stop) {
  new_num = round((new_num + 1) * 1.55)
  num = c(num, new_num)
}

head(num,-1)
# [1]   1   3   6  11  19  31  50  79 124 194 302 470 730
```

Answer (score 2):

## Reduce Solution

Here is a solution using `Reduce`

```
# framework
x0       <- 1
bound    <- 900
r        <- 1.55
estimate <- round(log(bound, r))
# iterations and filtering 
vec      <- Reduce(f = function(y,x) round((1+y)*r), x = 1:estimate, 
                   init = x0, accumulate = TRUE)
vec      <- vec[vec <= bound]
# result
[1]   1   3   6  11  19  31  50  79 124 194 302 470 730
```

**Notes**

- As mentioned in the comments, to have whole numbers one must use `round;floor;ceil;etc.`, I chose `round`. But the "true" values are not whole numbers.
- I calculate an `estimate` that I use in `Reduce` in order to have a rough idea of the size of the result - that can surely be done cleverer.

---

## Rcpp Solution

Here is a solution using the `Rcpp` package (so the function is written in `c++` and "transformed" into an `R` function). The function here uses a `while` loop, so pretty much @RonakShah's solution written in `c++`.

**C++ file**

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector nateCpp(int init, int bound) {
  int current   = init;
  int outLength = 1;
  NumericVector out(outLength);
  out[0] = current;
  while ((int) round((1+current)*1.55) <= bound) {
    current = (int) round((1+current)*1.55);
    out.insert(out.length(), current);
  }
  return out;
}
```

**R file**

```
# sourcing the file to have the function 
Rcpp::sourceCpp('MyCppFile.cpp')
nateCpp(1,900)
[1]   1   3   6  11  19  31  50  79 124 194 302 470 730
```

---

## Benchmarking

Here are benchmarking figures:

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr    min     lq      mean median     uq      max neval cld
   ronak(1, 10^5) 34.644 38.656 56.628269 40.844 52.878 25973.41 1e+05   c
    nate(1, 10^5) 36.103 40.844 57.294825 43.032 53.243 26714.79 1e+05   c
  darren(1, 10^5) 29.903 33.550 46.599951 35.374 41.209 12248.98 1e+05  b 
 nateCpp(1, 10^5)  2.553  4.012  6.578349  4.741  5.471 10963.14 1e+05 a
```

Unsurprisingly, the solution involving `c++` is by far the fastest. For the `R` only solutions,

- @DarrenTsai's recursion is the fastest (recursions should be used with caution though, problems such as too many nested expressions might arise - in this case it should be fine as the numbers grow rapidly) followed by
- @RonakShah's and my function.

**The functions**

```
ronak <- function(x0,stop) {
  new_num = 1
  num = 1

  while(new_num < stop) {
    new_num = round((new_num + 1) * 1.55)
    num = c(num, new_num)
  }

  head(num,-1)
}
nate <- function(x0, bound) {
  r        <- 1.55
  estimate <- round(log(bound, r)) 
  vec      <- Reduce(f = function(y,x) round((1+y)*r), x = 1:estimate, init = x0, accumulate = TRUE)
  vec      <- vec[vec <= bound]
  vec
}
darren <- function(start, end){
  n <- length(start) ; last <- start[n]
  if(last >= end)
    return(start[-n])
  else
    darren(c(start, round((last + 1) * 1.55)), end)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A **recursive** solution:

```
FUN <- function(start, end){
  n <- length(start) ; last <- start[n]
  if(last >= end)
    return(start[-n])
  else
    FUN(c(start, round((last + 1) * 1.55)), end)
}

FUN(1, 900)
# [1]   1   3   6  11  19  31  50  79 124 194 302 470 730
```